# native Array.filter doesn't work on $resource items

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I try to apply a function to a native `filter()` call on an array (returned from $resource), I get an undefined error:

```
            Job.query().$promise
                .then(function(data){
                    var all = data;
                    var lastDay =  all.filter(lastDay);
                    var lastWeek =  all.filter(lastWeek);

                    $scope.jobs.day = lastDay.length;
                    $scope.jobs.week = lastWeek.length;
                });
```

I get `all.filter` is undefined.

Comment: `data` is not instanceof `Array`?

Comment: No, actually its an object.

Comment: `filter` is method of `Array` instance. You need to write custom code to filter object properties.

Comment: actually, the problem was the function `lastDay` and `lastWeek` were `undefined` inside the callback. Not sure why, they are hoisted to the top of the controller.

Comment: On what basis you wnat to filter **** all.filter(lastDay) *** what is this lastDay. I think lastDay and lastWeek  is not a function

Comment: I had a variabled and a function w/ same name.